# rotate a projection to follow mouse drag

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a project to generate world map projections and manipulate them. You can see a beta version here : http://ansichtssache-n.ch/en/personas/daVinci

I'm trying to get the drag event correctly interpreted, so that for example when you drag Australia up, it actually moves Australia up and not the center of the projection (causing Australia to move down in a Miller projection).

I've been trying to find the correct rotation angles to apply to the 3 axis as shown here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4282586 .

I can get the x/y position on the canvas from the start and end of the mouse drag, I can get the geo-coordinates of these points too, and I can get the x/y of the current center as well as its geo-coordinates, but honestly I'm stuck now...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here [Compose two rotations in D3 geo projection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964993/compose-two-rotations-in-d3-geo-projection)

I came up with a way to compose the trackball rotation with the existing projection rotation so that you get intuitive control regardless of the original globe orientation.

Comment: cool, thanks for sharing. I ended up trying to geo-localize the point clicked and record the rotations to determine how to translate the mouse movement into the d3 rotate matrix... it's really approximate but it's already better as before.

I'll look into your solution, and probably implement it when I get the time,

thanks again !

Comment: by the way if someone wants to check it out : http://ansichtssache-n.ch/en/personas/daVinci